# How to sort a string array in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How to sort the following string array in kotlin in alphabetic order?

```
val array = arrayOf("abc","bcd","xyz","ghi","acd")
```

Comment: it annoys me when people downvote new users without explaining why. Your question has been downvoted because questions on StackOverflow should be more specific. So you should show what you've tried and why it didn't wok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To sort the same array we can use

```
array.sort()
```

This inbuilt method will sort in alphabetic order.
We can also sort Int Array and other array types using inbuilt sort() method

To sort an array without changing the original we can use

```
val array = arrayOf("abc","bcd","xyz","ghi","acd")
val sorted = array.sortedArray()
```

as mentioned above answer by s1m0nw1

Answer (score 6):

It might be interesting to not modify the original array. Therefore `sortedArray` can be used:

```
val array = arrayOf("abc","bcd","xyz","ghi","acd")
val sorted = array.sortedArray()

println(array.contentDeepToString())
println(sorted.contentDeepToString())
//[abc, bcd, xyz, ghi, acd]
//[abc, acd, bcd, ghi, xyz]
```

It creates a new `Array` without modifying the original.

Otherwise, the original string array can be modified and sorted with `sort()`.